# Saving return value of a Expectation

Tags: jmock, expectations

I want to use return vale of a expectation to add to one more expection.
I have a m_accountProcessor object which has interface createAccount to create a new account and returns a Account object.
I want to save this object and add it to one more expectation for encode function call. How can I save the value?

```
       m_context.checking(new Expectations() {{

        one(m_accountProcessor).createAccount(CUSTOMER_DETAILS);
        //How can I save the return value of createAccount's Account object
         one(m_accountProcessor).encode(/*AccountObject*/);
       }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget, you're not calling the real account processor, you're imitating its behaviour. Create an account object in the test, you can return the using the

```
will(returnValue(account));
```

clause, and expect to have it passed back to the account processor for encoding.

Bonus questions, why are you getting an object out of the account processor and then passing it back for encoding?

Comment: as I said, create an account object in the test. which you can return from the createAccount expectation, then you can check that the same object is passed to the encode call.

and you still haven't answered the bonus question :)

Comment: I need to store both account id and encoded id in my table, to avoid calculating cpu intensive encoded id everytime it is required.

Comment: then I perhaps the encoding and account creation should belong to different objects, since they do different jobs?